# Remove nested array in nested foreach PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, nested

I have a problem in presenting data from a database using nested foreach. 
in the code that I worked on, I almost managed to provide data output from the transaction database as I expected in the form of a multidimensional array which in the second nested array contains the product sold and removes the duplicate data of the product sold.

and my problem is how to delete or not display the last nested array?

this is my code:

```
    public function resultSetFP()
{
  $this->execute();
  $res = $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP | PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 foreach($res as $key => $value){
   foreach($value as $v){
      foreach($v as $b){
         $res[$key][$b]=$b;
      }
   }
 }
 return $res;
}
```

output code:

```
    'P2-6/01/2018/094909/0001' => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          'Bid' => string 'Dagadu Bocah' (length=12)
      1 => 
        array (size=1)
          'Bid' => string 'HirukPikuk' (length=10)
      2 => 
        array (size=1)
          'Bid' => string 'HirukPikuk' (length=10)
      'Dagadu Bocah' => string 'Dagadu Bocah' (length=12)
      'HirukPikuk' => string 'HirukPikuk' (length=10)
  'P2-6/01/2018/095825/0002' => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          'Bid' => string 'Dagadu' (length=6)
      1 => 
        array (size=1)
          'Bid' => string 'HirukPikuk' (length=10)
      'Dagadu' => string 'Dagadu' (length=6)
      'HirukPikuk' => string 'HirukPikuk' (length=10)
```

I expected to remove the third nested array 
leaving the data that I marked:

```
    'P2-6/01/2018/094909/0001' => 
        array (size=5)
//removing this array
          0 => 
            array (size=1)
              'Bid' => string 'Dagadu Bocah' (length=12)
          1 => 
            array (size=1)
              'Bid' => string 'HirukPikuk' (length=10)
          2 => 
            array (size=1)
              'Bid' => string 'HirukPikuk' (length=10)
//leaving this
          'Dagadu Bocah' => string 'Dagadu Bocah' (length=12)
          'HirukPikuk' => string 'HirukPikuk' (length=10)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try that:

```php
foreach ($res as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $i => $v) {
        foreach ($v as $b) {
            $res[$key][$b] = $b;
        }

        unset($res[$key][$i]);
    }
}
```